#  Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

when i run this function in my project, i got a FormatException.

but i *can* run the same LINQ expression in "LinqPad"

```
  private List<TNews> GetPagedEntities(int pagenum, int pagesize, IQueryable<TNews> query)
  {
            var totalCnt = query.Count();
            int recordsCount = (totalCnt < CONST_QUERY_COUNT) ? totalCnt : CONST_QUERY_COUNT;

            SetPagerValues(pagenum, pagesize, recordsCount);

            var newsRslt = (from m in query
                            orderby m.PnacDT descending
                            select m).Take(recordsCount).Skip(pagenum * pagesize).Take(pagesize).ToList();
            return newsRslt;
   }
```

ps:`CONST_QUERY_COUNT==10000`

what does this exception mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be your entity model and the database have some difference. It can be a data type mismatch  for a column.